# Windows 10 Ubuntu Nginx Port in Use

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, bash, nginx

I installed the windows 10 technical preview to use the Ubuntu subsystem, but upon installing nginx I can not start the service.

Here is the error log:

[image]

Comment: Windows 10 have iis  Is it running?

Comment: @Lenne no its not.

Comment: Tried myself, no matter what port I use, nginx say it is in use.. I Guess it is not ment to work...

Comment: Take a look at this http://superuser.com/questions/1107943/nginx-and-ubuntu-on-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Won't work.

http://www.pcworld.com/article/3050473/windows/heres-how-windows-10s-ubuntu-based-bash-shell-will-actually-work.html

> As Microsoft notes, “This is a developer toolset to help you write and build all your code for all your scenarios and platforms.” It’s not a full Ubuntu virtual machine. You can’t use it to host servers, as you could on Linux. If you need that, you can always install Linux in a virtual machine using Microsoft’s Hyper-V technology, VirtualBox, VMware, or something similar.”

Comment: I actually have a LAMP stack up and running so you _can_ run both a web and MySQL server. I haven't been able to get Nginx up and running, though. =/

Answer (score 4):

Comment out the ipv6 line in your sites-available conf and it will work like a charm.

1. Open your bash console
2. Run command: `apt-get install nginx`
3. Run command: `vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`
4. Comment out the ipv6 line (in bold):

   ```
   $server { 
       listen 80 default_server; 
   #   listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
   ```
5. Run command: `nginx`

For good measure I also changed it from port 80 to 8080 and was able to run a curl on it.

Comment: See the revised comment above.