# Nginx and Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I've downloaded an anniversary update for windows 10 and I've turn on Linux subsystem. I can normally install apache2 and everything is good, but when I try install nginx, yeah, it's install but it doesn't work. No message, no error, has anyone tried to set up nginx server on ubuntu on windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same issue and found [this](http://qiita.com/matarillo/items/ae62b1af761823b645b6)

In short:

Add master_process off; on nginx.conf
Remove the ipv6 listener on the default site.

Finally if sudo service start nginx is not working for you, try loading it directly using sudo /usr/sbin/nginx and kill it.  (sudo service start nginx didn't work for me the first time, i don't know why).